# Django Rest Framework - CreateAPIView ForeignKey lookup fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework CreateAPIView in order to create a comment. So far everything is OK and here is my code.

Models

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True)

class Comments(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Posts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=5000, null=True)
```

Serializer

```
class CommentCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields = [
            'content',
            'post'
        ]
```

and view

```
class CommentCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Comments.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentCreateSerializer
```

I sent a post request to the create route with `post(ID)` and `content` and everything worked. But the problem is I wanna pass post `slug` instead of post ID.

I am not sure how can I do that. I am familiar with lookup_fields but I am not certain how to apply them for ForeignKey match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) in `CommentCreateSerializer` to use **slug** instead of **pk** when you pass the `post` value on Comment Create request, like this:

```
class CommentCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    post = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=Posts.objects.all(), slug_field='slug'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields = [
            'content',
            'post'
        ]
```

Comment: Finally someone have something. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the CommentAPIview you need to overwrite the perform create method in to the lookup like so

```
def perform_create(self):
    post_pk = self.kwargs.get("post_pk")
    post  = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_pk)
    serializer.save(post=post)
```